# How to change selected item in a drop down populated with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am population a drop down with jquery ajax and after that I want to change selected Item.

The code I use for changing selected item works fine when I dont fill the drop down without jquery but it is not working when I fill it with ajax.

How to resolve it?

```
<select id="agent" name="AgentId"></select>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#agent").empty();
$.getJSON("/cpanel/rate/GetAgentsByPortId", { portId: $(this).attr("pol") }, function (data) {
    var i = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#agent").append("<option value='" + data[i].AgentId + "'>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
    }
});
$("#agent>option:eq(1)").attr('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX** is a short for ***Asynchronous JavaScript And XML***.

That means, the request is asynchronous, it's response happens sometime in the future, and so is the processing of the response. If the processing (appending of options) happens in the future, you can't use it's result (selecting an option) at current time.

Try like this:

```
<select id="agent" name="AgentId"></select>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#agent").empty();
$.getJSON("/cpanel/rate/GetAgentsByPortId", { portId: $(this).attr("pol") }, function (data) {
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#agent").append("<option value='" + data[i].AgentId + "'>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
        }
        $("#agent>option:eq(1)").attr('selected', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: In what way did it not work? besides, even if it didn't work, I hope you understood why your code ***can't*** work, and how to move towards a solution.